# How to subtract shapes in visio 2010

Tags: visio, shapes

Im using Visio 2010 from our msdnaa. Im searching the function to "substract" two shapes from eachother. E.g. i have a circle, but I only want the half circle, so I lay a rect over the circle and "substract" the shapes from each other.

When I search through the web I only find help for visio 2003. There must be such a function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't state if you are trying to do this manually or through automation.

If you are doing this manually you need to use [Shape Operations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/about-merged-shapes-HP001025415.aspx); in particular the Fragment operation. This operation is not on the ribbon. An easy way to find the Shape Operations is to turn on Developer Mode, see these instructions: [Working in Developer Mode](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/176f6300-9bfc-4a76-a59f-252e784ff897/). Alternately you can customize the existing ribbon to add the Shape Operations.

If you are trying to do this through automation you need the [Fragment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff768748.aspx) method on the Selection object.

Comment: The Developer Mode was exactly what I was searching for. If activated you find everything you need to subtract shapes etc. in the "Developer tab". Thank you very much!